# Extract Residence and Mobile Numbers from a string

Tags: php, string

I've a string in the following format:

```
$string="(R)66325xxx,66315xxx (M)9908717xxx,9441253xxx (O)40506xxx";
```

The numbers seperated by comma followed by (R),(M),(O) are the residence numbers, mobile numbers and office numbers respectively.

Ex:
Residence Number1=66325xxx
Residence Number2=66315xxx

Mobile number1=9908717xxx
Mobile number2=9441253xxx

Office Number1=40506070

I want to extract residence, mobile and office numbers from the input string in to an array as follows:

```
$residencenumber=array(66325xxx,66315xxx)
$mobilenumber = array(9908717xxx,9441253xxx)
$officenumber = array(40506xxx)
```

Can anyone help me creating the arrays from the inputstring.
Thank you

Comment: Is there always a space between a set of numbers?

Comment: Yes there is always a space between a set of numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$string="(R)66325xxx,66315xxx (M)9908717xxx,9441253xxx (O)40506xxx";
$temp = explode(' ', $string);

$residentnumber = explode(',', str_replace('(R)', '', $temp[0]));
$mobilenumber = explode(',', str_replace('(M)', '', $temp[1]));
$officenumber = explode(',', str_replace('(O)', '', $temp[2]));

print_r($residentnumber);
print_r($mobilenumber);
print_r($officenumber);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 66325xxx
    [1] => 66315xxx
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9908717xxx
    [1] => 9441253xxx
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40506xxx
)
```